# xDebug + Netbeans + PHP

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

Is it possible to debbuging with xDebug, NetBeans and PHP in all steps? Now I am able to  debug only if I know any step in project (I must set breakpoint), but I would like press `F5` on each step in project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. There are various tutorials out there: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html